# Visual Studio Code with OpenCV libraries

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

```cpp
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "Eigen/Dense"
```

I need to import these libraries in Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu.
OpenCV is present. Also C++14 libraries should be present in the editor.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the terminal and use
   `locate <file you want to include>`
2. Get the path of the file and ensure it is inside some include folder. For example:
   `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2`
3. Go to VS code press CTRL+SHIFT+P search for c/c++ edit configuration.
4. Inside c_cpp_properties.json file under include path add the path as shown:
   `{
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "Linux",
           "includePath": [
               "${workspaceFolder}/**",
               "/usr/local/include/opencv4"
           ],
           "defines": [],
           "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
           "cStandard": "c11",
           "cppStandard": "c++17",
           "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
       }
   ],
   "version": 4
   }`
   This is what worked for me.

Comment: The specific line that worked for me was: ``"/usr/local/include/opencv4"``
instead I had ``"/usr/local/include/opencv4/**"``

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following code. You may have to change your paths, in particular the Qt path. Also, I'm working with a MOSSE filter so that's my app name. Lastly, I'm on Linux (Ubuntu) so you might have to update the include path for your particular OS:

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "args": ["-g", "main.cpp", "-o", "mosse", "-I/usr/local/include/opencv", "-I/usr/local/include", "-L/usr/local/lib",
     "-lopencv_shape", "-lopencv_stitching", "-lopencv_objdetect", "-lopencv_superres", "-lopencv_videostab", "-lopencv_calib3d",
     "-lopencv_features2d", "-lopencv_highgui", "-lopencv_videoio", "-lopencv_imgcodecs", "-lopencv_video", "-lopencv_photo", 
     "-lopencv_ml", "-lopencv_imgproc", "-lopencv_flann", "-lopencv_core", 
     "-I/home/colm/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/include/", "-L/home/<username>/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib", "-lQt5Core", "-licui18n", "-licuuc", "-licudata"]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C++ Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/mosse",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": true,
      "linux": {
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "includePath": ["/usr/include"],
        "setupCommands": [
          {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "osx": {
        "MIMode": "lldb"
      },
      "windows": {
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
          {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "C++ Attach",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "attach",
      "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
      "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
      "linux": {
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
          {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "osx": {
        "MIMode": "lldb"
      },
      "windows": {
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
          {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run that programm using command line like this,
cd toYourDirectory
then
**g++  yourFileName.cpp -o  outputExecutableFileName  OpenCvPackageLocation**

For example in my case

```
g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Now do 'ls' , you will see a new file, which you write in place of outputExecutableFileName above (in my case it is main).

Do

./outputFileName (in my case it is ./main)

Hope it will help.

Answer (score -2):

I am using the c_cpp_properties.json file in the vs code for performing the task.

[Official Doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

Comment: Can you please add your c_cpp_properties.json file, as the official documentation does not show how to add the openCV.
This will make your answer more informative